# copy/paste charts - It is copying all together instead separately

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in ssrs 2008 and there are four separate charts in this report. My problem is that when I run this report on Internet Explorer and try to copy and paste this charts to powerpoint or excel, it is copying all of them together as one picture (right click - copy - paste). I want it to copy/paste separately based on user's choice. How may I provide it? Any help would be appreciated.

**Example**

```
CHART1    CHART2


CHART3    CHART4
```

What SSRS doing now after right click on CHART1 and copy/paste to excel:

```
CHART1
CHART2
CHART3
CHART4
```

All comes as one picture. What I wanna see:

```
CHART1
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned that this is a common bug when multipla charts are run on the same page. Adding a page break between the charts and displaying all the charts in separated pages solves this issue.